# jQuery html cause a memleak in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I have a problem with my single page application.
After some hours of use, I get the "He is dead Jim" in chrome
http://static02.mediaite.com/themarysue/uploads//2011/01/chrome-dead-jim-sad-tab.png

This seems to be caused by a mem leak issued through jQuery.html();
But only chrome/chromium seems to have this problem.

The IE and FF seem to clean up correct.

I have made an example:
http://www.mst.ch/fileadmin/chrome-mem-leak-demo/

and a demonstration video:
http://www.mst.ch/fileadmin/chrome-mem-leak-demo/chrome_mem_leak.mp4

Do someone know this issue and know how to fix this?

Comment: Without any code, how are people suppose to see where your leak is?

Comment: There is an example lini above with code. But it seams to be an chrome issue, as long the gc will not forced twice or the system is roun out of memory, the meory will not freed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .empty().html() instead of .html() to unbinds the event listeners.

it will release memory

Comment: My example has no events.